# Does a virtual machine have a virtual machine monitor by definition?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, operating-systems, computer-architecture

Saw this post but couldn't comment:

[VM sandboxing- what happens?](https://superuser.com/questions/483361/vm-sandboxing-what-happens)

Is it possible to have a virtual machine (vm) without a virtual machine monitor (vmm)/hypervisor, or if you have one virtual machine by default the logic which interfaces with the hardware is the vmm/hypervisor?

I am trying to understand if its the vm which does the sandboxing, or the vmm? and if it is the vmm, what does the vm do exactly- just provide the normal OS services?

Answer (score 0):

Running a program without its graphical user interface is sometimes referred to as running it headless.

Via Wikipedia:
A headless system is a computer system or device that has been configured to operate without a monitor (the missing "head"), keyboard, and mouse.

So the same concepts may apply to a virtual machine, you just use an alternate way of connecting to it, like ssh, Remote Desktop, or whatever methods are available to you.

---

If I am understanding correctly the vmm/hypervisor would be lower than the Operating system it is servicing.  So the virtual machine makes calls and everything like a normal program, it runs and when it needs something it makes requests like it would if it were the only OS.  Then if there is a call for something the OS handles, then that command is handled by the VMM to change  the instruction into an api call to the "real" os.

So yes, I believe the VM doesn't know anything about its circumstances, and the vmm is the virtualizer.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/vmms-versus-hypervisors)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor

Comment: Ok but my point is that the VM is exactly the same as a normal OS, its the VMM which does all the virtualization?